# date não mostra a data completa, somente o ano

Tags: php, data

Tenho essa situação que preciso pegar o ano atual e jogar na variável `janI` e `janF`, na tela mando um `echo` e exibe a data. Porém só está exibindo o 2019. O `/01/01` não está aparecendo. O que pode ser?

```
$ano=date('Y');
echo $ano;
$janI = $ano/01/01;
$janF = date('Y/01/31');
```

Comment: Tem erro de sintaxe no teu código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando você faz `$ano/01/01`, você está pegando o valor de `$ano` e dividindo por 1 duas vezes (ou seja, o resultado será o próprio valor de `$ano` - no caso, 2019). Isso acontece porque `$ano`, embora seja uma string, [é convertida para inteiro por estar em um contexto numérico](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion).

Mas se você quer datas referentes ao primeiro e último dia de janeiro do ano atual, pode fazer assim:

```
$d = new DateTime(); // data atual
$d->setDate($d->format('Y'), 1, 1); // mudar para 1 de janeiro deste ano
echo $d->format('Y-m-d'); // 2019-01-01
echo $d->format('Y-m-t'); // 2019-01-31
```

Na [documentação](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) você pode ver que o formato `t` mostra o último dia do mês (em vez do dia contido no `DateTime`).

---

Outra alternativa é usar [`strtotime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php), que aceita alguns [formatos especiais](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php) para criar datas específicas. Depois é só usar `date` para imprimir no formato desejado:

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('first day of january this year')); // 2019-01-01
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('last day of january this year')); // 2019-01-31
```

---

Se vai iterar por vários meses (conforme [seu comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/380210/date-n%C3%A3o-mostra-a-data-completa-somente-o-ano/380226?noredirect=1#comment752787_380226)), uma alternativa é setar a data inicial e ir somando um mês. Ex:

```
$d = new DateTime(); // data atual
$d->setDate($d->format('Y'), 1, 1); // 1 de janeiro do ano atual
$umMes = new DateInterval('P1M');
for ($i = 0; $i < 12; $i++) { // iterar por 12 meses
    echo $d->format('Y-m-d'). PHP_EOL;
    echo $d->format('Y-m-t'). PHP_EOL;
    $d->add($umMes); // ir para o próximo mês
}
```

Para somar um mês eu uso um [`DateInterval`](https://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php), que aceita uma string no [formato ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations). No caso, `P1M` corresponde a uma duração de um mês. O código acima imprime o primeiro e último dia de janeiro a dezembro de 2019.

Se quiser, pode chamar `setDate` passando os valores específicos, em vez de somar um mês. Adapte os valores de acordo com o que precisar. Se quiser voltar um mês, por exemplo, basta usar `sub` em vez de `add`.

Você também pode usar um valor de ano específico, em vez de usar o ano atual:

```
$d->setDate(2018, 1, 1); // 1 de janeiro de 2018
```

Enfim, mude os valores de acordo com o que você precisar, pois a lógica básica é a mesma.

Comment: na realidade eu quero pegar o primeiro e ultimo dia de todos os meses, porem depois vou passar de alguma maneira por exemplo 2018 e dai precisava de algo que desse para manter o padrao

Comment: @MuriloAlbeest Coloquei um exemplo básico, mas se não for o que vc quer, eu sugiro que vc [edite sua pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/380210/edit) detalhando exatamente o que precisa.

Comment: acabei utilizando a ultima opção, mas deu certo. obrigado a todos